# Python Set_Blob_Metadata and the self positional argument

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I've been playing around with Python for the last day trying to understand the benefits of Azure Blob Storage and how it works. What i'm trying to do is add metadata to an existing blob using the script below:

```
blob_client.set_blob_metadata(
                        account_url = "https://storage01.blob.core.windows.net/",
                        container_name="container",
                        blob_name="template.json",
                        metadata={'metadata1': '1111'})
```

However it fails with the error message: TypeError: set_blob_metadata() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

I have no clue why? I've checked several samples on Github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your full script, I could only make a guess.
You have to create an instance of `BlobClient` in order to call `set_blob_metadata` method.
This should be something like:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(blob_url="https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob-name")
blob_client.set_blob_metadata(
                        account_url = "https://storage01.blob.core.windows.net/",
                        container_name="container",
                        blob_name="template.json",
                        metadata={'metadata1': '1111'})
```

I am guessing you just create a reference of `BlobClient` rather than an instance, like in below:

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
blob_client = BlobClient # This is wrong
blob_client.set_blob_metadata(
                        account_url = "https://storage01.blob.core.windows.net/",
                        container_name="container",
                        blob_name="template.json",
                        metadata={'metadata1': '1111'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that was the problem. But somehow it still showed an error message: resource not found. Doublechecked it by opening the URL, eventually went with a SAS signature and that worked.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
```

sas_url = "https://scalesetdiag.blob.core.windows.net/container/document.txt?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2020-01-01T17:09:21Z&st=2019-12-28T09:09:21Z&spr=https,http&"
blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(sas_url)

blob_client.set_blob_metadata(
                        metadata={'metadata1': '1111'})